Add file to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your Info.plist React Native Webview
I've implemented a WebView in my current react native application it is working fine URLs are opening in the WebView. Upon testing this on iOS I came across this warning Error: Unable to open URL: Add file to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your Info.plist. I'm unable to understand what I should do so that this warning should not occur anymore. Also, curious that if I don't resolve this issue and upload my app for submission will my app gets rejected because of this?
Below is my code for webview component:
export const WebView = ({
url,
visible,
closeWebView,
}) => {
const [error, setError] = useState({
http: false,
https: false
})
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
const [siteUrl, setSiteUrl] = useState('');
const renderError = (errorDomain, errorCode, errorDesc) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.renderErrorContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.loadPageText}>Cannot Load Page</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

useEffect(() => {
    httpSiteUrl = url.startsWith('http://') ? url : url.replace('www.', 'http://');
    httpsSiteUrl = url.startsWith('https://') ? url : url.replace('www.', 'https://');

    const checkHttpUrl = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(httpSiteUrl);
            setSiteUrl(res.url);
        } catch (error) {
            setError((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                http: true,
            }));
        }
    };

    const checkHttpsUrl = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(httpsSiteUrl);
            setSiteUrl(res.url);
        } catch (error) {
            setError((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                https: true,
            }));
        }
    };
    checkHttpsUrl();
    checkHttpUrl();

}, [url]);

return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Modal
            visible={visible}
            onRequestClose={closeWebView}
        >
            <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>{title}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={closeWebView}>
                    <AntDesign name='close' size={wp(6)} color={COLOR.black} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            {
                (error.http && error.https)
                    ?
                    null :
                    !isLoaded ?
                        <Progress.Bar progress={progress} width={null} height={3} borderWidth={0} />
                        :
                        null
            }
            {
                (error.http && error.https) ?
                    renderError()
                    :
                    <RNWebView
                        source={{ uri: siteUrl }}
                        style={{ flex: 1 }}
                        // renderLoading={LoadingIndicatorView}
                        // startInLoadingState={true}
                        onLoad={() => setIsLoaded(true)}
                        onLoadProgress={(event) => setProgress(event?.nativeEvent?.progress)}
                        renderError={renderError}
                        onNavigationStateChange={(state) => {
                            setTitle(state?.title)
                        }}
                    />
            }
        </Modal>
    </View>
)

}
